# How to monkeypatch the registry connection with pytest

Tags: python, registry, pytest, monkeypatching, winreg

I am currently writing unit tests for my python script. One of my functions has the following code:

```
from _winreg import *

aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, LIBRARIES_REG_KEY)

count, value, type = QueryInfoKey(aKey)

ver_list = [EnumKey(aKey, x) for x in range(count) if EnumKey(aKey, x).startswith(version)]
```

I am using monkeypatch for most of my tests. I was wondering if there was a way to monkeypatch the ConnectRegistry (or even the OpenKey) function to return the data I want. I would feed it different data and test the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is the import actually in the function being tested? If not, would something like this work?

```
def my_CR(arg1, arg2):
    return something_useful

def my_OK(arg1, arg2):
    return something_else_useful

def test_myfunc():
    ConnectRegistry = my_CR
    OpenKey = my_OK
    assert function_calling_CR_and_OK(...) == expected_value
```

Would you also need to monkeypatch OpenKey and EnumKey?

Comment: No, the import is not in that function. I thought there was a way to mock the OpenKey function to return some kind of registry key object that would contain the data I want and that would be interpreted as a valid key by the EnumKey function. Is it possible or is there a limitation that would obligate me to patch all three of those? Because if I patch the three functions, there isn't much left to test...

Comment: @Amaranth: I'm guessing these functions access the system registry on a Windows machine? I don't really know much about how that works. If you can control what comes back from my_CR and my_OK such that OpenKey and EnumKey do something reasonable without patching, I would think you'd be fine. Your tests might only work with the right stuff in the registry though, i.e., only on your machine or only on machines that are configured just so.